# Help identifying 1.25mm pin pitch, 15-pin connector (crimped)

Tags: connector, identification

Please help identifying this connector:

- measured pin pitch: 1.25mm (17.5mm/14); may also be 1.27mm
- 15 pin (female), single row
- crimp connectors
- 1.5mm width (thickness)

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

photos of the socket:

[image]
[image]

Comment: "measured pin pitch: 1.25 (17.5/14)"  What units? Inch? mm?

Comment: it should be mm, sorry

Comment: Could that be 1.27 mm?

Comment: > could that be 1.27 mm
I don't have access to any calibrated measuring equipment. Using standard office ruler the distance from the left edge of the leftmost socket to the left edge of the rightmost socket is around 17.5mm. If the pin pitch was 1.27 the total distance would be 17.78, so yes, that could be 1.27 mm pin pitch.

Comment: I've added photos of the matching socket

Comment: For your search efforts, 1.27 mm pitch should give more results.

Comment: It looks very much like Hirose DF13 (DF13C-15P-1.25V) but with a latch (https://www.hirose.com/product/series/DF13). Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Male versions that would plug onto:

https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-headers-male-pins/314?k=connector&k=&pkeyword=connector&sv=0&pv1989=0&pv1790=6848&pv88=97513&pv90=39665&sf=1&FV=-8%7C314&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25

Look at some of those, the bottom of the page has Mating Products to get you to female housings like you are after.

Comment: Thanks. I've done digikey, mouser, arrow and tme.eu search to no avail.

Answer (score -1):

Looks similar to Hirose DF14 [series](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/DF14)

Comment: The DF 14 is unlatched. OP's connector is latched